# admob for javascript not working

Tags: javascript, admob

I'm trying to include ads in a web page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 100px; ">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var admob_vars = {
      pubid: 'a150bdd0d7d7f00', // publisher id
      bgcolor: '000000', // background color (hex)
      text: 'FFFFFF', // font-color (hex)
      test: false // test mode, set to false if non-test mode
     };
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I can not see the ads and I get no erros, not even javascript errors. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine and if you use something like :

```
console.log(_admob.vars_cache)
```

in your browser you will see that. :)

Comment: No and there is no URL call going out. Please share the reference URL for the ads app you are using.